# how to view React native app in browser http://192.168.1.13:19000/

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my terminal log below

I have tried **exp://192.168.1.13:19000** to run the app in the browser

```
13:56:43: Starting packager...
Packager started!
Your app is now running at URL: exp://192.168.1.13:19000

View your app with live reloading:

  Android device:
    -> Point the Expo app to the QR code above.
       (You'll find the QR scanner on the Projects tab of the app.)
  iOS device:
    -> Press s to email/text the app URL to your phone.
  Emulator:
    -> Press a (Android) or i (iOS) to start an emulator.

Your phone will need to be on the same local network as this computer.
For links to install the Expo app, please visit https://expo.io.

Logs from serving your app will appear here. Press Ctrl+C at any time to stop.

 › Press a to open Android device or emulator, or i to open iOS emulator.
 › Press s to send the app URL to your phone number or email address
 › Press q to display QR code.
 › Press r to restart packager, or R to restart packager and clear cache.
 › Press d to toggle development mode. (current mode: development
```

**this is what I see :**

[exp://192.168.1.13:19000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6hPf.png)

**This is my project navigator.** I don't know if I am supposed to have an entry point like an **index.html** or other :

[project navigator in visual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts9BN.png)

I have also tried to run  **//192.168.1.13:19001** :

[//192.168.1.13:19001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnxvL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to the same problem:

Download the (Expo XDE) desktop application it will solve your problem.

Steps:

1-download Expo XDE for your appropriate OS(ie. windows or mac) from https://expo.io/

2-open Expo XDE and you will find your CRNA project , click on specific project you want to run.

3- click on the gear icon in address bar and select host as a Lan , here you will find your "ipAddress:host"

paste this address to your expo mobile App in explore section
and if everything is right then you will get your application running on your mobile.

Hope it works..

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can run your app on any device (web, android or ios) in expo.
Go to https://expo.dev and in the left nav bar, select "Snack" option. It creates a new project for you to develop, and you can download project as zip even.